# Write data with headers to .txt

Tags: python, io

my code contains a loop and I want to save what obtained in each step. Now I am printing the variables using `print index, peak_number, our_blob_area, our_blob_CM, filename`; how could I save them in a file, with a header stating the variables name?

Comment: Check out the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

With the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) perhaps:

```
with open('outputfile.csv', 'wb') as outfh:
    writer = csv.writer(outfh)
    writer.writerow(['index', 'peak_number', 'our_blob_area', 'our_blob_CM', 'filename'])

    for something in something_else:
        writer.writerow([index, peak_number, our_blob_area, our_blob_CM, filename])
```

This'll write one row with headers, then every time you pass another list to `writer.writerow()` a new line is written with those values, comma-separated.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x, [`print` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) optionally accepts `>> file_object`:

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    print >>f, 'index, peak_number, our_blob_area, our_blob_CM, filename'
    for row in data_source:
        print >>f, index, peak_number, our_blob_area, our_blob_CM, filename
```

In Python 3.x, use [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) as function and pass optional `file` argument:

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    print('index, peak_number, our_blob_area, our_blob_CM, filename', file=f)
    for row in data_source:
        print(index, peak_number, our_blob_area, our_blob_CM, filename, file=f)
```